# Postgresql query with Interval (hours) does not work with hours < 12

Tags: postgresql

I´ve a query on my database with the following syntax:

```
select * 
from machine_data 
where machine_id = :machineId 
and TO_DATE(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS') > (NOW() - ((interval '1 hours') * :hours)) 
order by timestamp;
```

that works fine with ":hours >= 12". Although there are values to get within < 12 hours, the query with ":hours < 12" is always empty. What am I doing wrong. I.e. this is one of the timestamps: "2020-11-03T10:51:19+01:00" in 24h time format...

Regards

Comment: Why isn't a column named `timestamp` defined with the data type `timestamp` (or even better `timestamptz`)?

Comment: Unrelated, but you can simplify your condition by using `now() - make_interval(hours => :hours)`

Comment: If you query doesn't return anything for values with less than 12 hours, then your table doesn't contain values that match that condition.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your problem is caused by comparing a **date**, which has no time information, with a timestamp with time zone.  You are basically asking if a certain day is greater than or equal to a specific time.  Because postgres will automatically cast the timestamp with time zone to a timestamp without time zone to perform the comparison, the results of this comparison will depend on the time zone of your **session**.

Here's an example:

```
select '2020-11-03'::date,
       hours,
       now() - ((interval '1 hours') * hours) as comparison_time,
       '2020-11-03'::date > now() - ((interval '1 hours') * hours) as is_greater
FROM generate_series(0,24) as g(hours);

    date    | hours |        comparison_time        | is_greater
------------+-------+-------------------------------+------------
 2020-11-03 |     0 | 2020-11-03 08:42:33.293542-05 | f
 2020-11-03 |     1 | 2020-11-03 07:42:33.293542-05 | f
 2020-11-03 |     2 | 2020-11-03 06:42:33.293542-05 | f
 2020-11-03 |     3 | 2020-11-03 05:42:33.293542-05 | f
 2020-11-03 |     4 | 2020-11-03 04:42:33.293542-05 | f
 2020-11-03 |     5 | 2020-11-03 03:42:33.293542-05 | f
 2020-11-03 |     6 | 2020-11-03 02:42:33.293542-05 | f
 2020-11-03 |     7 | 2020-11-03 01:42:33.293542-05 | f
 2020-11-03 |     8 | 2020-11-03 00:42:33.293542-05 | f
 2020-11-03 |     9 | 2020-11-02 23:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    10 | 2020-11-02 22:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    11 | 2020-11-02 21:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    12 | 2020-11-02 20:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    13 | 2020-11-02 19:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    14 | 2020-11-02 18:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    15 | 2020-11-02 17:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    16 | 2020-11-02 16:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    17 | 2020-11-02 15:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    18 | 2020-11-02 14:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    19 | 2020-11-02 13:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    20 | 2020-11-02 12:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    21 | 2020-11-02 11:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    22 | 2020-11-02 10:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    23 | 2020-11-02 09:42:33.293542-05 | t
 2020-11-03 |    24 | 2020-11-02 08:42:33.293542-05 | t
```

Your query should likely use to_timestamp instead of to_date.  If the timestamps in your table are not at the same time zone as your session, you will need to carefully convert them.

Comment: Thx Jeremy, yes, I missed to use TO_TIMESTAMP on my date string. My new query is
"select * from machine_data where machine_id = ? and TO_TIMESTAMP(replace(timestamp, 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > (NOW() - ((interval '1 hours') * ?)) order by timestamp". On save of those timestamp string I use moment.js in this way: "moment().utc().format()" - together this works now. Regards